# Mysql st_intersects + st_buffer doesn't work

Tags: mysql, gis, geospatial, spatial

I tried to test if a line is met in some distance from a point. St_distance just gives me what I want. However, I'm curious about st_intersects + st_buffer:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper


mysql> set @l4=st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(50 50, 52 45)');
mysql> set @g4=st_geomfromtext('POINT(50 49)');
mysql> select st_distance(@l4, @g4);
--------------
select st_distance(@l4, @g4)
--------------

+-----------------------+
| st_distance(@l4, @g4) |
+-----------------------+
|    0.3713906763541037 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would think the point is very close to the line but obviously MySQL disagrees:

```
mysql> select st_intersects(st_buffer(@g4, 1), @l4);                                                                                                              
--------------
select st_intersects(st_buffer(@g4, 1), @l4)
--------------

+---------------------------------------+
| st_intersects(st_buffer(@g4, 1), @l4) |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why? Do I miss something?

P.S.
I have tried the commands above in H2GIS and it says it is indeed true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ST_Intersects should return true in this case.

This appears to be the bug reported here:  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71076, and fixed in MySQL 5.7.6, according to the release notes here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,629183,629183

"This work also corrected issues that [...], and that
       ST_Intersects() sometimes incorrectly calculated the
       result for intersections of LineString and Polygon."

Comment: Thanks @Ireeder. I thought about firing a bug report but wasn't sure. Good to know it's done.